# Capture JSP source after static includes?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm getting JSP errors and can't figure out which file&line is causing them because of static includes. In my logs I see a line-number from the outer JSP after all static includes (my outer jsp has 110 lines of code, but the error line number is 3106).

Is there a way to get the final source of my outer jsp after all static includes, so I can see where that line-number actually points? Can I run preprocessor somehow?

Comment: if you are using Tomcat then see below tomcat\work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSP translated files are stored (in Tomcat) in

```
    /work/Catalina/localhost/[your_app_context]/org/apache/jsp/...
```

We Should check in other containers or web servers also.

See the below hieararchey 
[image]

Comment: This answer is probably best I can get.

What I wanted to see: my usual JSP files with "<jsp:include>" and "<@% include >" replaced with included content (inline).